# setText talking only single character instead of string

Tags: android

```
 private String[] questions = {"1. Java was invented in 1222",
        "2. Constructor overloading is not possible in Java",
        "3. Assignment operator is evaluated Left to Right.",
        "4. Variable name can begin with a letter, \"$\", or \"_\"",
        "5. Interfaces can be instantiated",
        "6. A .class file contains bytecodes?",
        "7. James Gosling is father of Java?",
        "8. Objects of a subclass can be assigned to a super class reference.",
        "9. Is java a programming language?",
        "10. java is only Interpreted"};
```

this is String[] of questions

```
textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    int index = 0;
    textView2.setText(questions[index]);
```

when I use setText on TextView, and try to set questions index 0 string
Result
[image]

Only 1st Character is set by this, please tell me if there is any problem in this code

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="10dp" android:layout_height="18dp" android:layout_marginBottom="73dp" android:textSize="18sp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.521" />
```

Comment: Have you set a character limit on your TextView? I ran this & got the right string back.

Comment: Please, post the code of the `TextView` from Your XML file.

Comment: <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.521" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the xml that you have posted it looks like the width is not correct.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="18dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.521" />
```

You have provided 10dp as width for your text view and that is why it is not able to show you the entire content. Changing this to `wrap_content` or `match_parent` will fix it.